# OSX Swing: Dynamic com.apple.laf.ScreenMenuBar content configuration

Tags: java, macos, swing, menubar

I have a cross-platform swing application with dynamic MenuBar content, eg. on every "File → Recent" menu open, there could be a completely different menu items list, depending on recent opened files.

For **Windows** there is no problems with it, I've overridden `JMenu.setPopupMenuVisible(boolean)` method and I refresh my items list before `super.setPopupMenuVisible(b)` call.

But for **OSX** I use system MenuBar which uses wrapper for all related components (wrapper clesses are ScreenMenuItem, ScreenMenu and ScreenMenuBar), so I do not receive any mouse events for my JMenu-components and cannot override any method.

Any suggestions or workarounds?

**SSCCE**

```
public class MenuBarTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                start();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void start() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        JMenu recent = new JMenu("Recent") {
            @Override
            public void setPopupMenuVisible(boolean b) {
                removeAll();

                Random r = new Random();
                int amount = r.nextInt(5) + 1;

                for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
                    add(new JMenuItem(String.valueOf(i + 1)));
                }

                super.setPopupMenuVisible(b);
            }
        };

        fileMenu.add(recent);
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);

        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        frame.setSize(200, 150);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I remember battling similar issues some time ago.. However, for your use case (recent files menu), I believe you could just change/update the menu items each time a file is opened in your application? It doesn't need to happen when the user interacts with the menu.

Comment: @haraldK *Recent files* thing is just example. My situation is more complicated. But, if there is no better way, I would be forced to do some similar, unfortunately.

Comment: *"My situation is more complicated."* Then you should probably describe the real situation in the question. We ain't mind readers... ;-)